# ConstraintLayout not respecting constraints

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I understand how to use the constraint layout on Android but I have faced this issue for the second time now and wished to know if there is a remedy or it is a bug with it.
I have set all constraints correctly in my layout my preview is revealed as seen on this photo
[image: Preview image]

The corresponding xml is as seen below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/root_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.auth.PlaceOfDeliveryFragment">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_select_city"
            style="@style/ToolbarStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_chevron_left_white_32dp"
            app:title="@string/text_select_delivery_city"
            app:titleMarginStart="75dp"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarStyle"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/colorTextWhite" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
            style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/city"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/country_spinner">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/city_text_input"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textCapWords" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/country_spinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:entries="@array/countries"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="@string/country_hint"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar_select_city" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/button_next"
            style="@style/NoInsetsButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/next_txt"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_white_24dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But when the app is run, I instead see the button hanging when I constrained it to the bottom of the layout.

[image: Preview]

I wish to understand if there is anything I am missing and the button hanging.

Comment: I tried your layout and its working fine for me.My guess is the style inside the material button is somehow causing this effect. Can you try removing the style in material button and test again?

Comment: Yeah, or post what "@style/NoInsetsButton" has within it so that we can troubleshoot from there?